Problem when printing hex value read from disk by ASM
I'm currently trying to implement Writing a Simple Operating System —
from Scratch by Nick Blundell.
The code is based on the routine on p.32-33:
org 0x7C00 ; BIOS loads boot sector to 0x7C00
bits 16 ; 16 bit mode
%define ENDL 0x0D, 0x0A ; new line characters
hex_buffer: db '0x0000', 0 ; buffer to store hex string


start:
    jmp main ; jump to main


; load DH sectors to ES:BX from drive DL
; Output: None
disk_load :
    push dx ; Store DX on stack so later we can recall
    ; how many sectors were request to be read ,
    ; even if it is altered in the meantime
    mov ah , 0x02 ; BIOS read sector function
    mov al , dh ; Read DH sectors
    mov ch , 0x00 ; Select cylinder 0
    mov dh , 0x00 ; Select head 0
    mov cl , 0x02 ; Start reading from second sector ( i.e.
    ; after the boot sector )
    int 0x13 ; BIOS interrupt

    ; check for error
    jc disk_error ; Jump if error ( i.e. carry flag set )
    pop dx ; Restore DX from the stack
    cmp dh , al ; if AL ( sectors read ) != DH ( sectors expected )
    jne disk_error ; display error message
    
    ; if no error, print success message
    lea si, [disk_success_msg] ; load address of disk_success_msg to SI
    call print ; call print function

    ret


; print string
; Input: SI = pointer to string
; Output: None
;
print:
    pusha ; save registers
.loop:
    lodsb ; load byte from [SI] to AL and increment SI
    or al, al ; check if AL is 0 (end of string)
    jz .done ; if AL is 0, jump to done

    mov ah, 0x0E ; teletype output
    int 0x10 ; call BIOS interrupt

    jmp .loop ; loop

.done:
    popa ; restore registers
    ret ; return

; print hex value 
; Input: DX = value to print
; Output: None
;
print_hex:
    pusha
    mov bx, hex_buffer ; store pointer to hex value
    add bx, 0x5     ; move pointer to end of string

loop:
    mov cl, dl  ; copy dx  value into cl
    cmp cl, 0   ; check if 0
    je end_loop ; if 0 then we're done

    and cl, 0xF ; mask first half byte
    cmp cl, 0xA ; compare to A
    jl lt_A     ; if <  A go to lt_A
    jmp gte_A   ; if >= A go to gte_A

lt_A: ; add 48 
    add cl, 48  ; add 48 to bring it to ascii '0'
    jmp end_cmp ; go to end of this code block
gte_A: ; add 55
    add cl, 55  ; add 55 to bring it to ascii 'A'
    jmp end_cmp ; go to end of this code block

end_cmp:
    mov [bx], cl  ; put value into dereferenced pointer
    sub bx, 1     ; decrement pointer
    shr dx, 4     ; shift right 4 bits to get the next half byte
    jmp loop      ; go back to start of loop

end_loop:
    mov si, hex_buffer   ; print the string pointed to
    call print ; by SI
    popa
    ret


main:
    ; setup data segment
    mov ax, 0 
    mov ds, ax  ; set data segment to 0
    mov es, ax  ; set extra segment to 0

    ; setup stack
    mov ss, ax  ; set stack segment to 0
    mov sp, 0x7C00 ; set stack pointer to 0x7C00

    ; print message
    lea si, [msg] ; load address of msg to SI
    call print ; call print function

    ; load sectors
    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl ; save boot drive

    mov bp, 0x8000 ; base pointer to 0x8000
    mov sp, bp ; stack pointer to 0x8000

    mov bx, 0x9000 ; buffer address
    mov dh, 5 ; read 5 sectors
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE] ; boot drive
    call disk_load ; call disk_load function

    mov dx , [0x9000] ; Print out the first loaded word, which
    call print_hex ; we expect to be 0x1989 , stored
    ; at address 0x9000

    mov dx , [0x9000 + 512] ; Also, print the first word from the second
    call print_hex ; 2nd loaded sector : should be 0x0604


end:
    hlt ; halt the CPU
    jmp end ; loop forever

msg: db "System booting", ENDL, 0 ; message to print



disk_error_msg: db "Disk error", ENDL, 0 ; disk error message

disk_success_msg: db "Disk read successfully", ENDL, 0 ; disk success message

disk_error:
    lea si, [disk_error_msg] ; load address of disk_error_msg to SI
    call print ; call print function
    jmp end ; loop forever

; Global variables
BOOT_DRIVE : db 0 ; boot drive

times 510-($-$$) db 0 ; fill the rest of sector with 0s
dw 0xAA55 ; boot signature

; We know that BIOS will load only the first 512 - byte sector from the disk ,
; so if we purposely add a few more sectors to our code by repeating some
; familiar numbers , we can prove to ourselfs that we actually loaded those
; additional two sectors from the disk we booted from.
times 256 dw 0x1989
times 256 dw 0x0604

But I found the output to be 0x19890x1604 instead of intended 0x19890x0604. Why? is my print_hex function implemented incorrectly? Rest of the code are mostly copied from the book.
Later I've found that the first digit of the second word is always replicating the first digit of the first word, e.g.
if we define
times 256 dw 0x9989
times 256 dw 0x0604
it will output 0x99890x9604 as a result.
If the first digit of the second word is not 0, the problem will not occur.
Problem solved: the hex_buffer is not reset after each print_hex call. Solution:

print_hex:
    pusha
    mov bx, hex_buffer ; store pointer to hex value
    add bx, 0x5     ; move pointer to end of string
    mov byte [hex_buffer + 2], 48 ; reset hex_buffer as '0x0000' as the digits can be changed by previous calls
    mov byte [hex_buffer + 3], 48 
    mov byte [hex_buffer + 4], 48 
    mov byte [hex_buffer + 5], 48 
    
loop: ;...


Learn to use a debugger. Also, reduce your problem. If it's a printing issue you (and we) don't need to deal with reading a disk. See also [mcve]. Anyway, yes, your print_hex is broken because it exits the loop when cl is zero so it is not printing 4 digits. As such, the 1 from the 1989 remains in the buffer. If you want 4 digits just use a loop that runs 4 times.

Thanks to your comment, I've found out the error pattern and I'm trying to fix it.

@Jester Thanks to your comment, I've already found out that the buffer is not cleared.  Instead of modifying the loop I found a solution to reset the buffer at the start of each call

That will not work in all cases. Try printing 0x0100. If you want 4 digits, run the loop 4 times.

If you always want 4 digits (including leading zeros), you can extract them in printing order, high nibble first, with a rotate left by 4.  See How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string? .  Since you're ultimately using a 1-byte-at-a-time print function, you can just inline that into the hex-print function instead of using a buffer at all.  If you want to take an early-out, you need to check for the whole number becoming zero, not just one nibble or byte as Jester points out.  But then you need to reset the buffer, creating more work.
